How can I use ExifTool to parse the filenumber from the filename, and use the filenumber in the destination filename?
This ExifTool command can be used to put a file from the current folder, e.g., IMG_7198.HEIC, into a particular folder path with a filename that contains the create date and time.
exiftool -d "%Y/%m/%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S 0%%c.%%e" '-filename<$CreateDate' .
Assuming the original filename contains the filenumber (e.g., 7198 from IMG_7198.HEIC), how could the filenumber be parsed from the original filename and used in the destination filename?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about photography. It is just a file management and shell scripting problem and should be asked on SuperUser or another SE site specific to your OS.

You can use the %f variable and edit it as described in the "Advanced Features" section of the -w (-TextOut) option.
The %f variable hold the base filename of the file. Since you want to drop the first 4 characters, you would use .4 between the percent sign and the f, e.g. %.4f.  This would leave you with just the numbers.
Because this will be used in a -d (-dateFormat) format string, the % signs need to be doubled, similar to what is done with the %c and %e in your example command.
In this resulting command, I replaced your origianl 0%%c with %%.2c. This causes the %c count variable to be automatically padded to two numbers, i.e. it will number 01-09 and then proceed with 10+
exiftool -d "%Y/%m/%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S %%.4f %%.2c.%%e" '-filename<$CreateDate' .


Thank you for your response, this answers my question. I adapted the syntax you shared and these commands help organize photos/live photos/videos from iPhone ~/Image-ExifTool-12.87/exiftool -fileorder -FileName -d '%Y/%m/%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S %%.4f.%%e' -TagsFromFile %d%f.HEIC '-filename<$CreateDate' ., ~/Image-ExifTool-12.87/exiftool -d '%Y/%m/%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S %%.4f.%%e' '-filename<datetimeoriginal' .
